# how to write datasets to xml in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have just started learning asp.net with c# and want to know how to write datasets to XML using asp.net.
Can anyone provide me any example or reference so that I can move ahead.

Thanks in Advance

Anu Sharma

Answer (score 1):

The `WriteXml` method will save the entire dataset to an `xml` file or stream.

```
myDataset.WriteXml("dataset.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one empty data dataset with database name, so that this name will reflect to your converted xml document

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.DataSetName = "ds";
```

Add your data (data tables) to this dataset with name

```
data.TableName = "tb";
ds.Tables.Add(data);
```

Create one XmlDocument & load data string into it

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, ds);
        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}

XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
_doc.LoadXml(result);
```